# Start Sql Agent Service with non-administrator priviliges

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I'm trying to start SQL Server Agent service with domain account that is not part of administrator group. I found this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms143504(v=sql.110). Steps I did:

1. Granted access in Local Security Policy

   - Log on as a service
   - Replace a process-level token
   - Bypass traverse checking
   - Adjust memory quotas for a process
2. Granted full control in regedit: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server
3. Edited NTFS permissions:

   - Instid\MSSQL\binn
   - Instid\MSSQL\Log
   - 110\com
   - 110\shared
   - 110\shared\Errordumps

I have not just granted NTFS permission on ServerName\EventLog. What folder is it? Do I need to do something else?
I can not change log on account from configuration manager because there are not all services are listed, only Browser service.

Comment: Did you try this method: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlupdates/2015/05/15/how-to-start-or-stop-sql-services-without-os-admin-rights/

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, that is not for my case. I just do not want to give admin rights for the account that is used as logon account for agent service

Comment: There's no need for the Agent Service account to be a Windows Administrator, and the permissions it needs are granted to the per-service SID on installation, so there's no need for you to grant anything to the service account.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, I want to change service account that was specified on installation. And yes I'm doing all this stuff to not grant windows administrator rights

Comment: Why change the default service account?  It’s not a Windows administrator.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, I'm trying to set domain account to the service. This domain account has some rights on another SQL Server. And I need to run jobs that connects to that server through linked servers

Comment: Then just set the account using SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, I already told that I cant do that because not all services are listed in SSCM

Comment: Did you have multiple versions of SQL installed on this server? If so, you very possible have multiple versions of configuration manager as well. Each version of configuration manager will only show the services that are compatible with that version of configuration manager. For example, I have a server that was upgraded to 2017 from 2017. The 2016 configuration manager only shows SSIS because it's still a compatible version (13.0), but the 2017 configuration manager shows all of my services.

Comment: @GreyOrGray, for now there is only one version (2012) installed. Maybe there were older versions before, I don't know. But SSCM links to c:\Windows\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager11.msc which is correct version for SQL Server 2012 according to this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: If there was a previous version, you'd see it in the same path, it would just have a different number after SQLServerManager. Do you see the various SQL services listed in the Services control panel? Perhaps there's a permissioning issue with WMI that isn't allowing SSCM to query the information.

Comment: @GreyOrGray, can you say path to folder "ServerName\EventLog", pls? That is only folder to which I have not granted privileges. I also have tried to repair installation, but did not help

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "ServerName\EventLog" in the documentation just refers to the windows event log. The Agent account should have full control. You should go into c:\Windows\SysWOW64\ and see if there are other SQLServerManager msc files there. Doing all of this configuration manually rather than fixing the SSCM issue could leave you worse off than you started.